# Group Anagrams Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, anagram

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem however I can not seem to find out how to match my output with the expected output.

Here's the problem:

**Given an array of strings strs, group the anagrams together. You can return the answer in any order.**

**An Anagram is a word or phrase formed by rearranging the letters of a different word or phrase, typically using all the original letters exactly once.**

And here's my solution:

```
class Solution(object):
    def groupAnagrams(self, strs):
        if len(strs) == 0:
            return []
        else:
            first_word = strs[0]
            anagrams = [first_word]
            strs = strs[1:]
            for word in strs:
                x = True
                for letter in word:
                    if word.count(letter) != first_word.count(letter):
                        x = False
                        break
                if x:
                    anagrams.append(word)
            for idx in anagrams:
                if idx in strs:
                    strs.remove(idx)
            return anagrams, self.groupAnagrams(strs)
```

Here's what my output is:

`[["eat","tea","ate"],[["tan","nat"],[["bat"],[]]]]`

And here's what my expected output is:

`[["bat"],["nat","tan"],["ate","eat","tea"]]`

I am still trying to get comfortable with recursion, so it's hard for me to visualize what is happening (even with a debugger). Any help on what is causing additional brackets to form is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns tuple

```
(anagrams, self.groupAnagrams(strs))
```

So, when it is applied recursively, each call inserts another tuple into the previous one. And this creates nested brackets. Try replacing your return statement with

```
return [anagrams]+self.groupAnagrams(strs)
```

This should make your function return list which will grow with each recursive call without adding excessive brackets.